# Identifying ascending and descending order or Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know how we can identify that descending order `Range` is given.

I have a test case where range is given in `(1..-1)` and `to_a` method gives empty array for same.

```rb
(1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(5..1).to_a
=> []
```

Help me write a condition which can confirm descending order `Range` is given.

Comment: Are you only interested in integer ranges?

Comment: Yes @Stefan I only wanted it for integer range.

Answer (score 4):

Range has [Range#first](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-first) and [Range#last](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-last) methods.

```
r = (5..1)
r.first > r.last # => true
```

Comment: I don't need reverse array, I just want to Identify or catch that reverse range is given.

Comment: He is asking how to identify whether range is given in an order or descending order.

Comment: Oh, ok, looks like I misunderstood you, I've updated my answer.

Comment: ...or `r.begin > r.end`. Consider remove prompts (e.g., "2.6.3 :023 > ") for a cleaner look. At first glance, `> r.first > r.last` looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Range#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/Range.html#method-i-size):

```
(5..1).size.zero?
#⇒ true

(1..5).size.zero?
#⇒ false
```

Comment: OR `Enumerable#none?` if I had my druthers

Comment: This will give a false positive for an exclusive range with the same `begin` and `end`: `(1...1).size # => 0`

Comment: @JordanRunning depends on what do we call “false positive.” Is `1...1` actually not reversed?

Comment: Yes, `1...1` is actually not reversed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to check for a reverse range:

```
(5..1).to_a.empty? #=> true
(1..5).to_a.empty? #=> false
```

---

If you want to have an array as output, you could do

```
r.to_a.then { |ary| ary.empty? ? (r.end..r.begin).to_a.reverse : ary }
```

The output for the two cases are:

```
r = (5..1) #=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
r = (1..5) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..5).to_a.present? ? "Ascending" : "Descending"
```

if value present in array means it **Ascending** or **Descending** cause if you give **(5..1)** range it create blank Array.